# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error in Signalr Hub

Tags: signalr, webapi, asp.net-core-signalr, .net-8.0

I'm getting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Error in Signalr Hub. Project is ".net 8"

I have this line in my program.cs file.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy",
        builder => builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed((hosts) => true));
});
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");
```

Comment: Hi Kübra Özyurt, could you share an update on this issue, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use blow code could help you fix the cors issue. The middlewares order are very important.

[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
...

namespace AspCore7_Web_Identity
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            ...
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            }));

            ...
            

            var app = builder.Build();

            ...

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            // Use Cors here
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Messaging}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            app.MapRazorPages();

            app.MapHub<MainHub>("/mainhub");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

If I disable cors feature in signalr server and I will face below issue .

[image]